How to compare/evaluate MATH dataset?
When evaluating llm, we often has the need to compare a dataset's answer and llm's answer.
But in math dataset,
the answer is in \box{...}, I can extract the answer,
but sometimes then answer is not a number, but \frac{-33}{2},
like here,this is $\boxed{k = \frac{-33}{2}}$, how do I compare to my llm output?
other place like $\boxed{\frac{sqrt(3)}{3}}$,my llm outputs $\boxed{\frac{1}{\sqrt(3)}}$
how do I compare them?
Unlike in gsm8k dataset, where the answer is after #### and is just a number,
so I can as least compare them. How do I handle MATH dataset?

Have you checked out  symbolic mathematics library like SymPy which allows you to represent mathematical expressions symbolically and provides functionality to simplify and compare them?
